# Coerce all columns to numeric but one, with variable number of columns

Tags: r, xml, tidyr

I have several xml files that I'm extracting one by one and converting into multiple dataframes (one per file).
The thing is that those xml files have slightly different data structures.
You will find below the code to extract one of those files, and an example of an xml file at the bottom of the post.

As you can see, there are some lines with single values (only m1),
or multiple values (m1, m2, m3),  like `<liasse code="068" m1="000000000040570" m2="000000000002193" m3="000000000038376"/>`.
The code right here is a reprex:

```
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse")
if(!require(xml2)) install.packages("xml2")
if(!require(lubridate)) install.packages("lubridate")

doc <- xml2::read_xml(PATH_TO_THE_FILE) %>%
  xml2::as_list() %>%
  purrr::pluck("bilans","bilan")


identite <- tibble::tibble(siren = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "siren", 1), 
                           code_greffe = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "code_greffe", 1),
                           date_cloture_ex = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "date_cloture_exercice", 1) %>% lubridate::as_date(),
                           date_cloture_ex_n.1 = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "date_cloture_exercice_n-1", 1) %>% lubridate::as_date(),
                           duree_exercice_n = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "duree_exercice_n", 1),
                           duree_exercice_n.1 = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "duree_exercice_n-1", 1),
                           statut_saisie = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "code_motif", 1),
                           type_bilan = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "code_type_bilan", 1),
                           confidentialite = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "code_confidentialite", 1),
                           nom = doc %>% purrr::pluck("identite", "denomination", 1))


n = lubridate::year(identite$date_cloture_ex)
n.1 = lubridate::year(identite$date_cloture_ex_n.1)

data <- doc %>% purrr::pluck("detail") %>% 
  purrr::map_df(~purrr::map_df(.,~attributes(.)))
```

Now, to coerce everything but "code" in numeric format, and put everything in order, nested:

```
data_num <- tibble::tibble(code = data$code, 
                            m1 = as.numeric(data$m1), 
                            m2 = as.numeric(data$m2),
                            m3 = as.numeric(data$m3))
full <- tibble(identite, data_num)
full_nested <- full %>% tidyr::nest(data = c(code, m1, m2, m3))
```

It works but presents a major problem. In some files there is an "m4" line. But if I add `m4 = as.numeric(data$m4)` as well as modify last line to `full_nested <- full %>% tidyr::nest(data = c(code, m1, m2, m3, m4))` in the present case, it will send back an error stating that m4 does not exist.

Therefore, the only solution I see is to tell R: coerce everything to numeric except the column "code", and finally nest anything except all "identite" (identity) variables.
But I can't figure out how to implement those *except* statements.

Thank you for having read my post!

Here is the xml example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bilans xmlns="fr:inpi:odrncs:bilansSaisisXML" version="1.0">
   <bilan>
      <identite>
         <siren>7541834956</siren>
         <date_cloture_exercice>20210101</date_cloture_exercice>
         <code_greffe>7803</code_greffe>
         <num_depot>0945383</num_depot>
         <num_gestion>1945852</num_gestion>
         <code_activite>4332B</code_activite>
         <date_cloture_exercice_n-1>0439543851</date_cloture_exercice_n-1>
         <duree_exercice_n>12</duree_exercice_n>
         <duree_exercice_n-1>12</duree_exercice_n-1>
         <date_depot>20210210</date_depot>
         <code_motif>00</code_motif>
         <code_type_bilan>S</code_type_bilan>
         <code_devise>EUR</code_devise>
         <code_origine_devise>O</code_origine_devise>
         <code_confidentialite>0</code_confidentialite>
         <info_traitement />
         <denomination><![CDATA[hidden]]></denomination>
         <adresse><![CDATA[nowhere]]></adresse>
      </identite>
      <detail>
         <page numero="01">
            <liasse code="014" m1="000000000001671" m2="000000000001671" />
            <liasse code="028" m1="000000000021557" m2="000000000019525" m3="000000000002032" />
            <liasse code="040" m1="000000000001049" m3="000000000001049" />
            <liasse code="044" m1="000000000024277" m2="000000000021196" m3="000000000003081" />
            <liasse code="050" m1="000000000060031" m3="000000000060031" />
            <liasse code="068" m1="000000000040570" m2="000000000002193" m3="000000000038376" />
            <liasse code="072" m1="000000000009806" m3="000000000009806" />
            <liasse code="084" m1="000000000032908" m3="000000000032908" />
            <liasse code="092" m1="000000000004742" m3="000000000004742" />
            <liasse code="096" m1="000000000148057" m2="000000000002193" m3="000000000145863" />
            <liasse code="110" m1="000000000172334" m2="000000000023390" m3="000000000148944" />
            <liasse code="120" m3="000000000007600" />
            <liasse code="126" m3="000000000000760" />
            <liasse code="134" m3="-000000000044214" />
            <liasse code="136" m3="-000000000012606" />
            <liasse code="142" m3="-000000000048461" />
            <liasse code="156" m3="000000000049178" />
            <liasse code="166" m3="000000000071965" />
            <liasse code="169" m2="000000000029740" />
            <liasse code="172" m3="000000000076261" />
            <liasse code="176" m3="000000000197405" />
            <liasse code="180" m3="000000000148944" />
            <liasse code="182" m3="000000000001415" />
         </page>
         <page numero="02">
            <liasse code="214" m1="000000000031915" />
            <liasse code="218" m1="000000000266718" />
            <liasse code="222" m1="000000000000835" />
            <liasse code="230" m1="000000000000178" />
            <liasse code="232" m1="000000000299646" />
            <liasse code="238" m1="000000000083038" />
            <liasse code="240" m1="000000000001500" />
            <liasse code="242" m1="000000000075261" />
            <liasse code="243" m1="-000000000000411" />
            <liasse code="244" m1="000000000003279" />
            <liasse code="250" m1="000000000100069" />
            <liasse code="252" m1="000000000045326" />
            <liasse code="254" m1="000000000001384" />
            <liasse code="256" m1="000000000002000" />
            <liasse code="262" m1="000000000000007" />
            <liasse code="264" m1="000000000311863" />
            <liasse code="270" m1="-000000000012217" />
            <liasse code="290" m1="000000000000564" />
            <liasse code="294" m1="000000000000024" />
            <liasse code="300" m1="000000000000930" />
            <liasse code="310" m1="-000000000012606" />
         </page>
      </detail>
   </bilan>
</bilans>
```

Comment: I have not loaded your sample data or anything, but I think you can use `across()`, something like `data %>% select(code, starts_with("m")) %>% mutate(across(starts_with("m"), as.numeric))`.

Comment: By the way, it also works without ```select(code, starts_with("m"))```.   
But another problem appeared now that I want to iterate over all xml files.    Some files don't have any "code" or "m1", "m2" etc. but only have the indentite, the rest being confidential. 
I am now trying to tell my script to ignore the full part about data. 
Should I ask another question referring to this one?

Comment: I included the `select` to mimic your code where you create `data_num`, which pulls out the `code` and `m` columns, but great if you don't need that. I'd ask another question and work on making it **minimal**. Here you share an XML file and a bunch of lines of working code to get it to the state where your problem starts. It's a more complete picture of your problem than needed. It's easier for us to understand and help if you cut out most of what works and focus just on the problem - share a `dput()` of a sample data right where the problem is rather than a bunch of code to get there.

Comment: Ok well noted, thx.